# Can __cplusplus ever be defined and equal to zero?

Tags: c++

The question came up of whether one should wrap `extern "C"` using `#if` or `#ifdef`. i.e.:

```
#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

Which begs the question: is there ever a situation where __cplusplus is defined to be equal to zero?

Comment: If you use a C compiler then `__cplusplus` won't be defined at all - thus I think `#ifdef` is the proper choice.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That is not necessary, you can `#if X` if `X` is undefined just fine, according to the standard.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard, the `__cplusplus` macro *must* be defined, the exact definition depends on the C++ standard being used but it will not be zero.

For example, for C++11 it *must* be `201103L`, with the note "It is intended that future versions of this standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value."

Historically, in some ancient non-conforming compilers you could probably dig up, `__cplusplus` was defined to 0 to indicate non-conformance with the standard. This is only of historical interest.

See: [How are the __cplusplus directive defined in various compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053960/how-are-the-cplusplus-directive-defined-in-various-compilers)

Comment: There were indeed such compilers, and Microsoft Visual C++ was one of them.

Comment: @EJP interesting, so `#ifdef` would *not* work with that compiler, mistakenly indicating you're compiling a C++ source when it's actually C?

Comment: @EJP or are you actually saying that it defined `__cplusplus` as `0` for a C++ build? In that case you *definitely* have to use `#ifdef` because `#if` will fail. I'm getting even more confused now.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I believe EJP is just mentioning which compiler had this behavior. You don't have to worry about it unless you are interested in retrocomputing.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Old Visual Studio C++ compilers were notoriously non-compliant, back in the Visual Studio 6 days and earlier, 20 years ago. Things are much better now.

Comment: I still have Visual Studio 6 installed at home, although it has been a long time since I've used it. I had to keep it around for years to compile my MFC projects.